# Different definitions of Morrey and Campanato Spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

The book by Giaquinta defines Campanato spaces using the seminorm:

$$[u]_{p,\lambda} = \left(\sup_{\substack{{x_0\in\Omega \\ 0<r<\text{diam}(\Omega)}}}r^{-\lambda}\int_{B_r(x_0)\cap\Omega}|u(x) - u_{x_0,r}|^p \right)^{1/p}$$

our lecture on the other hand uses:

$$[u]_{p,\lambda} = \left(\sup_{\substack{{x_0\in\Omega\\ 0<r<1}}}r^{-\lambda}\int_{B_r(x_0)\cap\Omega}|u(x) - u_{x_0,r}|^p \right)^{1/p}$$

and I have also seen the following definition used:

$$[u]_{p,\lambda} = \left(\sup_{\substack{{x_0\in\Omega \\ 0<r<\min(1,\text{diam}(\Omega))}}}r^{-\lambda}\int_{B_r(x_0)\cap\Omega}|u(x) - u_{x_0,r}|^p \right)^{1/p}$$

and similar for the definition of the Morrey spaces and for the definition "of type A".

Are those definitions equivalent? Or when are they equivalent?

Comment: I don't have access to Giaquinta's book at the moment;  what assumptions are you making on $\Omega$, and where does $\lambda$ appear in the definitions?

Comment: @AlexAmenta $\Omega \subset \Bbb{R}^n$ is a bounded, connected, open set. $p \geq 1$, $\lambda \geq 0$.

Comment: ok - you also need to replace $u(x_0)$ with $u(x)$ in the integrals.

i'll write $\delta = \operatorname{diam}(\Omega)$ to save space: when $\delta \leq 1$, the three definitions are equal, using that $B_r(x_0) \cap \Omega = B_{\delta}(x_0) \cap \Omega$ if $r > \delta$. When $\delta > 1$, the only part which is not clear is that the first definition is controlled by the second definition; I think some sort of covering argument may be used to prove this, but I can't work out the details. (it could be false for all I know, I've never thought of these spaces)

Comment: math.SE copy of this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/849411/different-definitions-of-morrey-and-campanato-spaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got an answer to the question meanwhile:

> The difference between the choice of upper bound $r$ is mainly related
>   to the assumptions one requires about $\Omega$. If $\Omega$ is
>   bounded, one wishes to have $A$ scaling-invariant and therefore
>   chooses $r = diam(\Omega)$. But any other finite number would work as
>   well. Therefore the choice of $1$ in the other definition. If $\Omega$
>   is not bounded on the other hand, one takes just $1$ by convention.
>   The upper bound does therefore change $A$ but not the fact whether a
>   $A$ exists or not therefore the set is still of Typ-$A$.

Comment: reason for the downvotes?